# How to split iText Paragraph into multiple columns?

Tags: itext

Is there any way I can split Paragraph data into multiple columns?

### Current Paragraph

```
 Something in the paragraph which need to read by the end user.
```

### Required Paragraph

```
Something in     ---------      to read by
the paragraph    ---------      the end user.
which need       ---------
```

Basically user wants to read shorter lines rather than a long line.

I am using itextpdf-5.4.4.jar Paragraph to display data.

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 2):

Please read my answer to the question [How to draw a rectangle around multiline text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29037981/how-to-draw-a-rectangle-around-multiline-text) for which I've written [DrawRectangleAroundText](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/objects/DrawRectangleAroundText).

In this example, we have a `Paragraph` with plenty of text:

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("This is a long paragraph that doesn't"
    + "fit the width we defined for the simple column of the"
    + "ColumnText object, so it will be distributed over several"
    + "lines (and we don't know in advance how many).");
```

And we distribute this paragraph over different lines like this:

[image]

For this purpose, we use the `ColumnText` class:

```
ct = new ColumnText(cb);
ct.setSimpleColumn(300f, 500f, 430f, 780f);
ct.addElement(p);
ct.go();
```

This is only a simple proof of concept. For more info about `ColumnText`, read the section *Absolute positioning of text* in the free ebook [The Best iText Questions on StackOverflow](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html). This way, you'll be able to avoid posting a question that can be answered by recycling an answer that was posted less than a day ago.