# using iText pdf api arrange data into multiple columns like below image attachment

Tags: java, itext

> Using Java Code and iTextPDF API  how to set data into multiple columns in
>   a single pdf like below attached image

[image]

Comment: Which iText version are you using?

Comment: iTextPDF-5.0.6 version

Comment: What research have you done? What effort have you made? This looks like a typical "I don't want to make any effort, write my codezzz for me" question. Show the code you've written, and indicate where the problem is.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of many other questions on StackOverflow, such as [How to split iText Paragraph into multiple columns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29042035) However, I chose [How can I add titles of chapters in ColumnText?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-can-i-add-titles-chapters-columntext) as duplicate because that answer contains the most elaborate example and screen shots that correspond with the screen shot added to the question.

Comment: By the way: why would you use iText 5.0.6 (February 2011) when the current version is iText 5.5.9 (March 2016) or even iText 7 (June 2016). In iText 7, it is **much easier** to render content in columns. See [Chapter 2](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-2-working-rootelement) of the [iText 7: building blocks](/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-2-working-rootelement) tutorial, and scroll to the part where you see screen shots of documents with columns.

Comment: Thank you very much  **Bruno Lowagie**