# IText PDF Element.Align_RIGHT, Element.Align_CENTER

Tags: java, pdf, itext

some days ago i asked a question about printing Rectangle outlining a text .
 [Here's is the answer for my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29037981/how-to-draw-a-rectangle-around-multiline-text). And this works perfect wenn text Alignment is Element.LEFT, which is default.

when i try to align text center or right, the text is drawn to a different potion than expected so that the Rectangle around the text is not corect.

am i doing some thing wrong?

For all alignments i am using this method in itext...

```
ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(cb);
ct.setSimpleColumn(llx, lly, urx, ury);
```

to get the widt i do...

```
ct.getFillWidth();
```

to get the height...`

```
ct.getYLine();
```

Why this doesn work for CENTER and RIGHT alignments?
[image: Please take a lokk to my results]

[image: this bold lines seems to be equal, but how to get it programmaticaly]

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're going to have to give us a little bit more information. Can you provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) we can use to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Ok i will try to extract this from mycode, but for now, please take a look to my edited image, the bold lines seems to equal, does it help?